# How to upgrade ElasticSearch from 6.8 to 7.X with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, elasticsearch

I have a Rails App using an `ElasticSearch` server, both of them are in there respective Docker Image.

I would like to upgrade my ElasticSearch server.  Actually I'm running `image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.1` and I would like to update it to `7.X`

With Version 7 I got this error when I'm rebuilding my Index:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [listing : {dynamic=true, properties={uid={analyzer=id_analyzer, type=text}, bee_id={analyzer=id_analyzer, type=text}, address={analyzer=address_analyzer, type=text}, location={type=geo_point}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [listing : {dynamic=true, properties={uid={analyzer=id_analyzer, type=text}, bee_id={analyzer=id_analyzer, type=text}, address={analyzer=address_analyzer, type=text}, location={type=geo_point}}}]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [listing : {dynamic=true, properties={uid={analyzer=id_analyzer, type=text}, bee_id={analyzer=id_analyzer, type=text}, address={analyzer=address_analyzer, type=text}, location={type=geo_point}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I know the error is cause by a breaking change, but I don't know how the fix it.

I'm using the `gem elasticsearch-model`:

My definition looks like this:

```
    include Elasticsearch::Model

    after_destroy { |record| ElasticIndexer.new(:delete, record.class.name, record.id) }
    after_save     { ElasticIndexer.new(:index, self.class.name, self.id)}

    index_name "#{Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore}_#{Rails.env} mydoc"
    document_type "mydoc"

def as_indexed_json(options={})
[....]
end

settings index: { number_of_shards:5, number_of_replicas:0 } do
      settings :analysis => {
        char_filter: {
          dash_remover: {
            type: "mapping",
            mappings: ["-=>"]
          }
        },
        filter: {
          english_stemmer: {
            type:       "stemmer",
            language:   "english"
          }
        },
        tokenizer: {
          id_tokenizer: {
            type: "ngram",
            min_gram: 3,
            max_gram: 3,
            token_chars: ["letter", "digit"]
          },
          address_tokenizer: {
              type: "edgeNGram",
              min_gram: 3,
              max_gram: 3,
              token_chars: ["letter", "digit"]
          }
        },
        analyzer: {
          description_analyzer: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: ['asciifolding', 'lowercase']
          },
          id_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: "id_tokenizer",
            char_filter: ["dash_remover"],
            filter: ['asciifolding', 'lowercase']
          },
          english_description_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: "whitespace",
            char_filter: ["html_strip"],
            filter: ['asciifolding', 'lowercase', "english_stemmer"]
          },
          address_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: "address_tokenizer",
            filter: ['asciifolding', 'lowercase']
          },
        }
      }
      mappings dynamic: true do
        indexes :location, :type => 'geo_point'
        indexes :uid,     :analyzer => 'id_analyzer'
        indexes :bee_id,  :analyzer => 'id_analyzer'
        indexes :address, :analyzer => 'address_analyzer'
      end
    end
```

What are the changes I'm supposed to apply?

Comment: Can you log the elasticsearch that is sent ? And have you also updated the elasticsearch ruby client ?

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel The problem is not when it's sent.  It's when I want to rebuild my Index.  Everything is up to date.

Comment: I meant the json query that returns the error.

Comment: @JudgeProphet did you ever resolve this issue? I'm seeing the same with searchkick and ES 7.

Comment: @MatthewFord  No, i'm sorry.  For now I'm still running 6.8 since I don't need the new feature and did not find any "how to"  that resolve my problems.

Comment: @MatthewFord Finally!  Check out my Answer, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I moved on to something else. After a long time, it was time to get back to it.

After reading a lot, I was looking at my code when I ran into this subtle line of code

I commented it out:
`document_type "mydoc"`
I give it a try.

What was my surprise when no error appeared in the console!
It works. (nice story)